# RxJs cartesian product of grouped hot observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, cartesian-product

**Motivation:**

The goal is to write a scraping library that allows extraction of relational / normalized data.

To that end, there are:

- source streams: emit cheerio documents: either by crawling urls or by scoping parent cheerio documents (e.g. cheerio document -> multiple cheerio documents, one for each li in the parent)
- table streams: emit table rows, subscribe to combinations of source streams and extract data from the given cheerio documents

As complex data requires multiple tables, each source stream is possibly subscribed to multiple times and needs to be shared as it contains side effects (crawling)

**Example: Blog**

On a simple blog there might be posts, authors and categories; The underlying data structure being e.g.

```
Post: {id, author, title, text}
Author: {id, name}
Category: {id, name}
author_post: {author_id, post_id}
post_category: {post_id, category_id}
```

To recreate the data structure from the scraped html, we create three source streams:

1. post: fed post urls, returns cheerio documents of posts
2. post.author: child to posts, follows hyperlink to the posts author and emits cheerio documents of authors
3. post.category: child to posts, returns a cheerio document for each category listed on the post (e.g. in '.categories li')

To recreate the post_category table, each post has to be combined with each category belonging to that post (== carthesian product).

My actual problem is even more contrived, as child streams already emit their own cheerio document as well as that of each of their parents i.e. {post: cheerio, author: cheerio}.

The problem of combining streams only comes up with e.g. siblings.

I also can't circumvent the grouping problem by emitting all children of a parent inside of one stream (e.g. {post, author, category}), as more complex data structures require grouping by grandparents

(I can provide an example for that if needed, but this is getting long enough as is).

**Problem**:

It's not possible to use groupBy and zip to combine groups of hot observables.

The GroupObservables emitted by groupBy emit their values as soon as they are created and zip waiting for all zipped observables to emit GroupObservables means missing any values emitted before the zip function is run.

**Question**:

How do I group and zip hot observables without losing values? Time information (e.g. all children emitting before the next parent emits) can't be relied on as children are possibly resolved asynchronously (crawled).

**More information:**

The best I can visualize it is this:

Child1 and Child2 are mapped versions of parent, C1C2 is the result of grouping Child1 and Child2 by parent and calculating the cartesian product inside those groups.

```
Parent: -1------2-------3--------

Child1: --a------b--c------------

Child2: ---1-2----3---4----------

C1C2:   --a1-a2---b3-c3-b4-c4----
```

Forming the cartesian product itself is no problem as there's an easy implementation (taken from issue #807 on RxJs, can't post more links)

```
function xprod (o1, o2) {
  return o1.concatMap(x => o2, (x, y) => [x, y]);
};
```

The problem is not missing any values.

**Edit**: 
[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sicuxunomi/edit?js,console) shows a simple situation: 1 parent, 2 children.

**References**:

- [question on RxJs Github](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/978)
  // removed additional links as I can only post 2

Comment: Improved description, however you are still mixing in my opinion too much problem description and implementation details (`stream is possibly subscribed to multiple times `, parent, child, sibling etc.). I still don't understand what is the output that you want. Is that the table streams? Is that the underlying data structure you gave?

Comment: In any case, if you have html documents (posts) and you want to generate `id, author, title, text`, `id` you generate yourself probably, `title` and `text` I imagine you don't have problems to get. To get `author` (only one by post right?), you need to fetch some other html document and extract the author information. Is that correct? That takes care of the first table in your underlying data structure. Same for `category` but there are several categories by post. each of those categories you extract only after fetching some html document. If this is all that is, no need for cartesian product.

Comment: If you do want to do the cartesian product of `author` and `category` my answer still should work. More on that later. Please confirm my understand is correct first.

Comment: The example of a blog is simplified - I can explain it in detail but I hope it suffices to say: I need to combine grouped streams & form the carthesian product inside matching groups

Comment: I can't really say if your understanding is correct, I guess I'm not able to articulate it any better for now - I'll try to make it more clear. Until then, thanks for your help :).

Comment: PS: Your example works but only without grouping: https://jsbin.com/dorebejayu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is a naive implementation of the grouping operator returning ReplaySubjects. While the solution is specific to my requirements, the general gist could be helpful:

```
Observable.prototype.splitBy = function(keySelector) {
  const parentObservable = this;
  let group, lastKey;
  return Observable.create(observable => {
    return parentObservable.subscribe(
      value => {
        const currentKey = keySelector(value);
        if(currentKey === lastKey) {
          group.next(value);
        } else {
          if(group) group.complete();
          group = new ReplaySubject();
          observable.next(group);
          group.key = currentKey;
          group.next(value);
        }
        lastKey = currentKey;
      },
      error => observable.error(error),
      completed => {
        group.complete();
        observable.complete();
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Now with RxJS version 7.5.4 I used nested operators, switchMap and map:

```
import { from, map, Observable, range, switchMap } from "rxjs";
let ar1 : number[][] = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
];

function cartesianProduct<T1,T2>(ob1:Observable<T1>,ob2:Observable<T2>):Observable<[T1,T2]>{
    return ob1.pipe(
        switchMap(function(i:T1):Observable<[T1,T2]>{
            return ob2.pipe(
                map(function(j:T2):[T1,T2]{
                    return [i,j];
                })
            );
        })
    );
}

cartesianProduct(range(0,3),range(0,3)).pipe(
    map(([i,j])=>ar1[i][j])
).subscribe(console.log);
```

I created coordinates [i,j] from [0,0] to [2,2] to access every cell inside the bidimensional array(ar1). I use two observable generators with range function that generate numbers from 0 to 2. So using my cartesianProduct function I generate all combinations of these two observables and save them as coordinates [i,j].
It should print in console all numbers inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

I add another answer here to what is my new understanding of your issue. I will delete it later if I misunderstood.

My understanding is:

- there is a parent observable which generate values
- those values are used by child1 to generate another observable which represents a sequence of values from an async operation ($.get, or whatever)
- same for child2
- one value of parent hence generate two observables, and you want the cartesian product of those two observables.

That code should do:

```
var parent = Rx.Observable.interval(500)
    .take(3)
    .publish();
var Obs3Val = function (x, delay) {
  return Rx.Observable.interval(delay)
    .map(function(y){return "P"+x+":"+"C" + y;})
    .take(3);
};
function emits(who){
  return function (x) {console.log(who + " emits " + x);};
}

var child1 = parent.map(x => Obs3Val(x, 200));
var child2 = parent.map(x => Obs3Val(x, 100));

Rx.Observable.zip(child1, child2)
             .concatMap(function(zipped){
  var o1 = zipped[0], o2 = zipped[1];
o1.subscribe(emits("child1"));
o2.subscribe(emits("child2"));
  return o1.concatMap(x => o2, (x, y) => [x, y]);
})
    .subscribe(function(v) {
                 console.log('cartesian product : ' +v);
               });

parent.subscribe();

parent.connect();
```

jsbin : https://jsbin.com/revurohoce/1/edit?js,console, https://jsbin.com/wegayacede/edit?js,console

Log :

```
"child2 emits P0:C0"
"child1 emits P0:C0"
"child2 emits P0:C1"
"cartesian product : P0:C0,P0:C0"
"child2 emits P0:C2"
"child1 emits P0:C1"
"cartesian product : P0:C0,P0:C1"
"cartesian product : P0:C0,P0:C2"
"child2 emits P1:C0"
"child1 emits P0:C2"
"cartesian product : P0:C1,P0:C0"
"child1 emits P1:C0"
"child2 emits P1:C1"
"cartesian product : P0:C1,P0:C1"
"child2 emits P1:C2"
"cartesian product : P0:C1,P0:C2"
"child1 emits P1:C1"
"cartesian product : P0:C2,P0:C0"
"cartesian product : P0:C2,P0:C1"
"child1 emits P1:C2"
"child2 emits P2:C0"
"cartesian product : P0:C2,P0:C2"
"child1 emits P2:C0"
"child2 emits P2:C1"
"child2 emits P2:C2"
"child1 emits P2:C1"
"cartesian product : P1:C0,P1:C0"
"cartesian product : P1:C0,P1:C1"
"child1 emits P2:C2"
"cartesian product : P1:C0,P1:C2"
"cartesian product : P1:C1,P1:C0"
"cartesian product : P1:C1,P1:C1"
"cartesian product : P1:C1,P1:C2"
"cartesian product : P1:C2,P1:C0"
"cartesian product : P1:C2,P1:C1"
"cartesian product : P1:C2,P1:C2"
"cartesian product : P2:C0,P2:C0"
"cartesian product : P2:C0,P2:C1"
"cartesian product : P2:C0,P2:C2"
"cartesian product : P2:C1,P2:C0"
"cartesian product : P2:C1,P2:C1"
"cartesian product : P2:C1,P2:C2"
"cartesian product : P2:C2,P2:C0"
"cartesian product : P2:C2,P2:C1"
"cartesian product : P2:C2,P2:C2"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your patience. I've updated my question to provide more information - sorry for being so long. As far as I can tell, your code works because the children are autonomous observables rather than mapped versions of a parent observable (see my example jsbin link)